# @Provides methods can only be present within a @Module or @ProducerModule

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, module, retrofit2

I wrote network module in project. I checked all similiar codes and qustions there are some people have same problem. But they all didn't solve this problem for me. I don't know what is problem here.

This is the error:

> error: @Provides methods can only be present within a @Module or @ProducerModule
> public static final com.technoface.iga.api.BoardingPassService postBoardingPassesRead(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()

NetworkModule.kt

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object NetworkModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideBaseUrl() = BuildConfig.BASE_URL

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideLoggingInterceptor(): HttpLoggingInterceptor {
        return HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
    }

    @ServiceInterceptorOkHttpClient
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providesServiceInterceptor(clientPreferences: ClientPreferences): ServiceInterceptor =
        ServiceInterceptor(clientPreferences)


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideOkHttpClient(
        logging: HttpLoggingInterceptor,
        @ServiceInterceptorOkHttpClient
        serviceInterceptor: ServiceInterceptor
    ): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(logging)
            .addInterceptor(serviceInterceptor)
            .build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideNetworkResultCallAdapterFactory(): CallAdapter.Factory {
        return NetworkResultCallAdapterFactory.create()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit(client: OkHttpClient, callAdapterFactory: CallAdapter.Factory): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(callAdapterFactory)
            .client(client)
            .build()
    }

@Provides
@Singleton
fun postBoardingPassesRead(serviceBuilder: ServiceBuilder): BoardingPassService = serviceBuilder.buildService(BoardingPassService::class.java)

@Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
annotation class BaseUrl

@Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
annotation class ServiceInterceptorOkHttpClient
```

BoardingPassServiceRepo.kt

```
class BoardingPassServiceRepo @Inject constructor(
    private val boardingPassService: BoardingPassService
) {
    suspend fun postBoardingPassesRead(boardingPassInfoRequest: BoardingPassInfoRequest) = boardingPassService.postBoardingPassesRead(
        encryptData(boardingPassInfoRequest)
    )
}
```

AppModule.kt

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideClientPreferences(
        @ApplicationContext context: Context
    ) = ClientPreferences(context)
}



class BoardingPassServiceRepo @Inject constructor(
    private val boardingPassService: BoardingPassService
) {
    suspend fun postBoardingPassesRead(boardingPassInfoRequest: BoardingPassInfoRequest) = boardingPassService.postBoardingPassesRead(
        encryptData(boardingPassInfoRequest)
    )
}
```

- Update Gradle version.
- Changed gradle version.
- Clean, Rebuild, Invalidate cache
- Deactivated Antivirus.

Comment: Are you using hilt or plain Dagger 2?
Where is ServiceBuilder dependency defined?  Could you please update it.